# How do I conditionally handle navigation in React Redux (React Native) based on result of dispatched action?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have the following component

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import React, { Component,PropTypes } from 'react';
import styles from './styles';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import EditProfile from '../../components/common/EditProfile'
import { saveProfile } from '../../actions/profile'

class Profile extends Component {

_saveProfile(){

    //I want to to dispatch this
    this.props.dispatch(saveProfile());

    //and if success push this route
    this.props.navigator.push({name:'Home'});

    //and if not, want to show an error message
}

render() {
    let {profile} = this.props;
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <EditProfile
                navigator={this.props.navigator}
                profile={profile}
                onSaveProfile={this._saveProfile.bind(this)}
            />
        </View>
      );
   }
}

Profile.propTypes = {
    navigator: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        dispatch
    };
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        profile: state.get("profile").profileState
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Profile);
```

I have the following action creators for this...

```
import facebook from '../api/facebook'
import * as types from '../constants/ActionTypes';

function saveProfileSuccess(profile){
    return {
        type:type.SAVE_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
        profile:profile
    }
}

function saveProfileError(error) {
    return {
        type:type.SAVE_PROFILE_ERROR,
        errorMessage:error
    }
}

export function saveProfile(profile){
  return dispatch => {
    profile.save(profile,(error,result)=> {
          if(error){
              dispatch(saveProfileError(error);
          }else{
              dispatch(saveProfileSuccess(result);
          }
    ));
  }
}
```

I don't have anything yet in a reducer because I am not sure how/what I need to do to conditionally handle saving a profile, handling an error message to the API, conditionally navigating to the home screen (as shown in first code snippet).

How is it that you dispatch an action from a component, and conditionally navigate away from that component on whether that action which makes an API call successfully or not. If it is not successful, I obviously want to show an error message and not navigate to another view.

Answer (score 0):

Since my reputation isn't high enough, I am not eligible to comment. But I had a doubt. You aren't passing any parameter as `profile` in your component while calling the action method 
    `this.props.dispatch(saveProfile())` that you are using in your action creators file
    `export function saveProfile(profile)`. Maybe I missed something.

Based on what I interpreted from your question, you want to perform navigation operations in your action methods based on conditions. If that's the case, the solution is pretty simple. Just pass the navigator reference(`this.props.navigator`), and the parameters required for navigating to next screen as an object, like in this case `{name: 'Home'}` as general method parameters to the action that you are calling to in the component.

For e.g.
In your component file, make the call as follows:

```
this.props.dispatch(saveProfile(profile, this.props.navigator, {name:'Home'})); // Pass the profile parameter according to your needs
```

And then in the action creators:

```
export function saveProfile(profile, appNavigator, navProps){
    return dispatch => {
        profile.save(profile,(error,result)=> {
            if(error){
                dispatch(saveProfileError(error);
            }else{
                dispatch(saveProfileSuccess(result);
                appNavigator.push(passProps); //Will push to Home Screen
            }
        });
    }
}
```